# Trying to open a docx document with Documents.Open("Path") throws an error

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm struggling to get one script running (https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Set-Outlook-20102013-8341e049) Basically when it tries to open a document it throws an error saying

```
 Sorry, we couldn’t find your file. Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?
```

It's probably not script's fault as I can't use this (example):

```
$MSWord = New-Object -ComObject word.application
$Test = $MSWord.Documents.Open('C:\Scripts\default.docx')
```

to work at all. I've read about making a Desktop profile in C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile but it makes no difference. Any way to get it working? I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: Try it on your desktop - could be a privilege escalation issue.

Comment: @ChrisN I was trying to get it working on my desktop. Haven't tried on server yet.

Comment: What error do you get when trying to create the COM object and open a doc outside of the script?

Comment: @MikeGaruccio I'm sorry but how exactly do I do it? I've been using Linux for a while and never been really scripting in batch/powershell so I'm pretty green.

Comment: no worries, just open a powershell console and type those two lines, hitting enter after each one.  and just to clarify are you running the set-outlook script from a windows or linux machine?

Comment: Second line makes the console spit out the same error I've stated above. I'm running Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason changing the code from

```
$MSWord = New-Object -ComObject word.application
$Test = $MSWord.Documents.Open('C:\Scripts\default.docx')
```

to

```
$Filename='C:\Scripts\default.docx' 
$MSWORD=New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$Document=$MSWORD.documents.open($Filename)
```

and then obviously replacing MSWORD with Document has solved the issue. I've no idea why would that work though.